# Issue when compiling `log` version "0.4.14"

Tags: rust

In my "Cargo.lock" file I see that `log{ version="0.4.14"}` is defined.
When trying to run some tests and compile my project I get the following:
[image]

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ValueBag<'_>: From<u128>` is not satisfied
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/log-0.4.14/src/kv/value.rs:364:21
    |
364 |                       Value::from_value_bag(value)
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<u128>` is not implemented for `ValueBag<'_>`
...
384 | / impl_to_value_primitive![
385 | |     usize, u8, u16, u32, u64, u128, isize, i8, i16, i32, i64, i128, f32, f64, char, bool,
386 | | ];
    | |_- in this macro invocation
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a ()>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a bool>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a char>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a f32>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a f64>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a i16>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a i32>>
              <ValueBag<'v> as From<&'a i64>>
            and 25 others
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<ValueBag<'_>>` for `u128`
note: required by a bound in `value::Value::<'v>::from_value_bag`
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/log-0.4.14/src/kv/value.rs:250:12
    |
248 |     fn from_value_bag<T>(value: T) -> Self
    |        -------------- required by a bound in this
249 |     where
250 |         T: Into<ValueBag<'v>>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `value::Value::<'v>::from_value_bag`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `impl_to_value_primitive` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I haven't defined `log` as a dependency for my project and thus I'm not sure what this error is, or how to possibly change the version of this dependency to a newer one that might resolve the issue.

Comment: There seems to be a solution found here: https://github.com/rust-lang/log/issues/500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a dependency which is restricting the version of `log` it uses, you should be able to solve this problem by running `cargo update`, which will edit the `Cargo.lock` file to update the `log` version in use to one without this bug (as well as any other minor/patch updates in dependencies).

If that doesn't work, you can use `cargo tree --invert log` to see a listing of which crates depend on `log`, all the way back to your own crates in your project. Then you can decide what to do about them.